# Cargar Select y TextArea Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, servlets

Estoy cargando un formulario el que debe cargar cierta información...
el tema es que no está funcionando...
Comparto el código, los datos son traidos desde Java

```
function llenarIndicadorActualiza(id_actividad){
    $('#modal_editIndicador').modal('toggle');
    var ID= id_actividad;
    console.log("ID"+ID);
    $.post('Mantenedor_Indiadores',{accion:2, id_actividad:id_actividad},function(Resuelto){
        for (var i = 0; i < Resuelto.length; i++) {
            var idArray = Resuelto[i].Id_Actividad; 
            console.log("idArray "+ idArray);   
            if(ID == idArray){
                var selectActividadActulizar            = Resuelto[i].id_areaEstrategica;
                var selectTipoIndicadoresActualizar     = Resuelto[i].Id_Tipo_Indicador;
                var edit_nombreIndicador                = Resuelto[i].Nombre_Indicador;
                var edit_formulaIndicador               = Resuelto[i].Formula_Indicador;
                var edit_lineaBaseIndicador             = Resuelto[i].Linea_Base;
                var edit_descIndicador                  = Resuelto[i].Descripcion_Indicador;
                var edit_medVerIndicador                = Resuelto[i].Medios_Verificacion;
                var edit_metaIndicador                  = Resuelto[i].Metas_Indicador;

                $('#selectActividadActulizar').val(selectActividadActulizar);
                $('#selectTipoIndicadoresActualizar').val(selectTipoIndicadoresActualizar);
                $('#edit_nombreIndicador').val(edit_nombreIndicador);
                $('#edit_formulaIndicador').val(edit_formulaIndicador);
                $('#edit_lineaBaseIndicador').val(edit_lineaBaseIndicador);
                $('#edit_descIndicador').val(edit_descIndicador);
                $('#edit_medVerIndicador').val(edit_medVerIndicador);
                $('#edit_metaIndicador').val(edit_metaIndicador);
                $('#edit_indicador_to_tabla').attr('onClick', 'actualizarIndicador('+id_indicador+');');
            }else{
                console.log("idArray else"+ idArray);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Observando que usas jquery para los selectores, si quieres cargar un select con el valor que proviene de alguna fuente (java,php, etc..), puedes hacerlo de esta manera si no funciona con el .val():

Para los select :

```
$('#selectActividadActulizar option[value='+selectActividadActulizar+']').attr('selected',true);
```

Para los textarea:

```
 $('#edit_nombreIndicador').text(edit_nombreIndicador);
```

Suerte..